# React ErrorBoundary - How to route to a component/homepage upon error in another route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-error-boundary

I was trying to figure out how to direct to my home page `/` if I have error in another page with route `/results`. I was able to redirect to my homepage with ErrorBoundary wrapped in my component but the route did not change and immediately it reverted to the same error. (I basically wanted to show up the homepage when there was error)

I tried with `react-router-dom` and render function at the ErrorBoundary component as below:

```
    render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={MyHomePage} />
            </Switch>
            
        </Router>);
    } else {
      return this.props.children;
    }
  }
```

But again the error appeared with the route remaining the same `/results` (and homepage not getting rendered with route `/`. Why is this happening? Can anybody please help to understand the reason.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with redirect component from `react-router`. Inside your if block instead of returning `Router` you can just return

```
<Redirect to="/" />
```

`Router and Switch` basically matchs browser URL and navigate but in your case you want to navigate programmatically based on condition so `Redirect` is more suitable here.